# index.php still needed, even after .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

So I have a server running on Digital Ocean. I'm trying to run Anchor CMS on it. So this is what the URL should look like `http://colourity.com/posts/hello-world`. But that doesn't seem to work. When I try `http://colourity.com/index.php/posts/hello-world`, all works fine. But the problem here is that I'm using `.htaccess` to correct this, here's what I have,

```
 Options -indexes

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 index.php
</IfModule>
```

That should of gotten rid of the `index.php`, additionally `mod_rewrite` is enabled. I've also restarted the server to see if that makes a difference, but it hasn't. Any ideas?

Comment: Does your apache configuration have [`AllowOverride All`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowoverride)? Otherwise, the `.htaccess` doesn't do anything.

Comment: That slipped. I got it working now. Consider writing it as an answer if you'd like. @Sam

Comment: Im not familiar with that Rule, usually is -- RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]  --- which redirect to any file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`AllowOverride All`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowoverride) must be included in the Apache configuration so that `.htaccess` rules can overwrite your configuration.  From the documentation:

> When the server finds an .htaccess file (as specified by AccessFileName) it needs to know which directives declared in that file can override earlier configuration directives.
>
> When this directive is set to None, then .htaccess files are completely ignored. In this case, the server will not even attempt to read .htaccess files in the filesystem.
>
> When this directive is set to All, then any directive which has the .htaccess Context is allowed in .htaccess files.

It's default value is `All`, but some template configuration files may have it manually set as `None`. Also note, that this syntax is only available in `<Directory />` sections.