# Deploy Laravel to domain subfolder

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel

#### Intro

I am struggling to deploy a Laravel project to a domain subfolder... Here's the complete "story":

My teacher has control of the machine at: http://ilp.fe.up.pt/
He created a user for me called **mitocondrias** so I could use it via **ssh** like:
`ssh mitocondrias@ilp.fe.up.pt`

He also set the usual `public_html` folder to be called `html` only.

So, to sum up, if I create a simple *hello world* `index.html` at `/home/mitocondrias/html/` I can successfully see it at http://ilp.fe.up.pt/mitocondrias/

---

#### What I did

Now, regarding the Laravel deploy, here is what I did:

I cloned my Laravel project called `CoExpr` to my user home: `/home/mitocondrias/coexpr`

I deleted the `html` folder and created a `symlink` to `/home/mitocondrias/coexpr/public` called `html` with the following command:

`mitocondrias@ilp:~$ ln -s ~/coexpr/public/ html`

So, here is the final tree structure:

```
ilp.fe.up.pt/        (the root of my teacher web hosting)
|
|-- mitocondrias/    (my user home, aka /home/mitocondrias)
|   |
|   |-- coexpr/      (the Laravel project)
|   |   |
|   |   |-- [...]
|   |   |-- public/
|   |   |-- [...]
|   |
|   |-- html/        (this is actually not a folder,
|   |                 but a symlink to /home/mitocondrias/coexpr/public/)
```

I also ran the following commands to set the correct Laravel permissions:

- `chmod -R 755 coexpr/`
- `chmod -R o+w storage`

---

#### The problem

After all this, I can successfully see the landing page at: http://ilp.fe.up.pt/mitocondrias/ (the equivalent of `localhost:8000` if I were serving the app with `php artisan serve`)

But when I try to use other routes, like: http://ilp.fe.up.pt/mitocondrias/explorer (the equivalent to `localhost:8000/explorer`) I get:

```
404 Not Found
The requested URL /home/mitocondrias/html/index.php was not found on this server.
```

What did I do wrong..?

---

#### Extra info

In case this is relevant, the `.htaccess` in `/home/mitocondrias/coexpr/public/` is as it was generated upon the Laravel project creation with composer - I did not touch it:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

And because of the `symlink`, this is also the `.htaccess` at `/home/mitocondrias/html/`.

---

#### End

So, that's it... Aff, this was a long post... Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe its easiest to just ask your teacher to use `public` as the web root instead of `html` and move everything up one level, getting rid of `coexpr/` and the symlink. Would that be possible?

Comment: Ah, maybe you have a duplicate slash in there. `ln -s ~/coexpr/public/ html` - looks like you might only need `ln -s ~/coexpr/public html`

Comment: @JanPapenbrock I think the slash right after public is indifferent

Comment: Yes, I think so, too. Check my answer below for the most probably solution.

Comment: @JanPapenbrock I'm waiting for my teacher to apply the changes (I'm not on the sudoers list). I'll come back to you as soon as I've got any news.

Answer (score 2):

[This related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13515278/1824988) provides a debugging hint: Check if the route works with `/index.php/`, to see if the problem is related to `.htaccess`.

Loading http://ilp.fe.up.pt/mitocondrias/index.php/explorer works!

So for some reason your `.htaccess` is not working.

Maybe simply enabling it will fix your problem, as stated [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24166637/1824988) to another related question.

Comment: After running `a2enmod rewrite` and editing `apache2.conf` to `AllowOverride All`, the `.htaccess` is still not working... Here is a copy of the current `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` : http://pastebin.com/raw/BN3hHjr7

Comment: Just to be clear of simple errors: Did you restart Apache after these changes? Also, is there a site-specific configuration for your VirtualHost - in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/yourfilename.conf`

Comment: Yes, we did restart Apache. Here is the content of `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf`: http://pastebin.com/raw/5TS8jnq9